# Translation of "I think eating good food is important ..."

Tags: traduction, verbes

"I think eating good food is very important to your health."

> Je pense que manger de la bonne nourriture est très important pour la santé.

Is it correct to use the infinitive form *manger* to translate the gerund "eating"? Or should I add *de*?

> Je pense que **de** manger de la bonne nourriture est très important pour la santé.

Comment: Why do you add a "de"?

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE I wasn't sure when "de" is needed. For example, it is used in this (similar) [sentence](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23489/translation-of-what-is-important-is-eating).

Comment: No, because in this other sentence, there is no "que". If you have "que" as relative pronoun, you don't need a "de". "que de" can't be. In your example, you have a Nom+C'est de+.infinitive... structure. For instance: La plus belle chose dans la vie, c'est d'être libre. C'est de.... Not the same thing here. It's a relative introduced by a relative pronoun. And the other thing, is that "manger de la nourriture" is not good French, because you always eat food, French language hates repeting things that are implicit or obvious. ex: Allumer la lumière.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE But isn't *allumer la lumière* commonly used?

Comment: Yes, it's used, you're right, but nobody can tell it's really good French, because of the obvious pléonasme. Manger de la nourriture is even worse, it looks like a foreigner is speaking or maybe a child who didn't realize he said twice the same thing. Good French must avoid redondance and pléonasme as much as possible.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE It also appears [in a dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/allumer).. If you want to say "turn the lights on", do you just say *allumer*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Même chose que la réponse que j'ai fait ici: [Translation of "What is important is eating ..."](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23489/translation-of-what-is-important-is-eating/23496?noredirect=1#comment45080_23496)

On ne dira pas "manger de la bonne nourriture", le français est une langue qui a horreur des pléonasmes.

- Je pense que bien manger est important pour la santé.

(ou d'autres expressions équivalentes à "bien manger", mais pas avec le redondant "nourriture")

- Pas de "de" après le "que".

Comment: Vous parlez «d'autres expressions équivalentes à *bien manger*» mais pourrait-on éviter le pléonasme (ici & dans l’autre question [+1 pour les 2, btw]) en tirant le verbe manger si l’on veut garder explicitement la notion de «bonne nourriture/alimentation» («L’important pour la santé, c’est une/la bonne nourriture/alimentation»/«Je pense qu’une/la bonne nourriture/alimentation est important pour..santé»)? In other words (& in my language), if mentioning eating adequately implies that we’re talking about eating FOOD, would mentioning food adequately imply that we’re talking about EATING it? Thx

Comment: Oui, exactement, quand on dit "Une bonne alimentation est nécessaire à une bonne santé/à la santé ("alimentation" est plus adroit que "nourriture"), on comprend qu'il s'agit de "manger"; Le français n'aime pas les redondances, il faut les éviter autant que possible.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer here is:

Je pense que manger de la bonne nourriture est très important pour la santé.

Here you are using the verb *penser* with the direct object, it means that the rest of the sentence is the answer of a *quoi*, *qui/que* question. So the natural way is to answer it with *que* directly followed by the infinitive form of the verb, here *manger*.

Using *de manger* would imply that you're using before a word that asking a question of the type *de qui ?*, *de quoi ?*. As example, you could say :" Je parle de mon meilleur ami" = "I'm talking about my best friend"

Comment: French Language (like all SE sites) is not a social game with right & wrong answers. **Good** answers are those that are supported by explanations. And there are often several good answers and not one single right answer.

Comment: Manger de la bonne nourriture n'est pas correct: C'est un pléonasme.

Comment: Selon vous, la nourriture ne peut être que bonne par définition ?

Comment: Non, c'est le mot "nourriture" qui gêne. On ne dit pas "manger de la nourriture", c'est un pléonasme. Au lieu de manger de la bonne nourriture, on dira "bien manger" ou d'autres expressions équivalentes. C'est un pléonasme, car on ne peut manger autre chose que de la nourriture...

Comment: Selon moi on peut manger autre chose que de la nourriture. La nourriture est par définition nutritive, or il est possible de manger ses ongles par exemple ou du poison.