# Translation of "What is important is eating ..."

Tags: grammaire, expressions, traduction

"What is important for your health is eating good food."

> Ce qui est important pour la santé, c'est manger de la bonne nourriture.
>
> Ce qui est important pour la santé, c'est **de** manger de la bonne nourriture.

Should the *de* be used? This is similar to [another question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23480/translation-of-i-think-eating-good-food-is-important) but with a different sentence structure. I think there are cases where *de* must be added when translating gerunds, but I'm not sure if this is one of those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4217) tells *de* must be used in such constructions (emphasis is mine).

> L'infinitif peut également avoir la fonction d'attribut du sujet,
>   c'est-à-dire qu'il est lié au sujet par le verbe être ou par un autre
>   verbe attributif (verbe d'état), comme sembler ou devenir. L'infinitif
>   en fonction attribut est **précédé de la préposition de** lorsque le sujet
>   n'est pas un autre verbe à l'infinitif et qu'il est repris par une
>   expression comme **c'est** ou ce serait.

I would add the variant without *de* is nevertheless common in spoken, colloquial French.

Comment: Yes, that's true, it can be heard orally, but is not grammatically correct. You're right.

Comment: only orally from people with bad French..

Answer (score 4):

- "Manger de la bonne nourriture" n'est pas du bon français.

C'est un pléonasme.

En bon français, on dirait "manger sainement", "bien manger".

Tout dépend si on "bonne nourriture" se réfère à de la nourriture de bonne qualité nutritionnelle, ou de la nourriture de bonne qualité tout simplement (bon goût, contraire du fast-food).
Mais ici, on a le contexte de "santé", donc on sait que c'est "sainement".
"Bien manger" pourrait être ambigu, vouloir dire, ou bien manger de la nourriture de bonne qualité, ou de la nourriture saine.

Une façon plus naturelle de le dire:

L'important pour la santé, c'est de bien manger.

OU

C'est de manger correctement. C'est de manger sainement.

Ma préférence va pour le: "C'est de manger sainement".

- La première phrase "L'important pour la santé, c'est manger..." est grammaticalement incorrecte. La deuxième phrase est bonne, à part le pléonasme à corriger.

Comment: Je ne traduirais pas pas _manger sainement_. L'original est _good_, pas _healthy_. Il est possible que l'ambiguïté soit délibérée.

Comment: On parle de "pour la santé", donc sainement s'applique tout à fait. Il faut tenir compte du contexte, comme je l'ai marqué dans ma réponse. La phrase n'est pas ambiguë en anglais, enfin je ne le pense pas.

Comment: _pour la santé_ traduit _for your health_. Si l'original n'a pas cru bon le répéter dans la suite, pourquoi la traduction devrait le faire? Effectivement le contexte est important, mais c'est celui qui entoure la phrase qu'il convient de prendre en compte.

Comment: Pour la santé, il est important de manger sainement = va de soi. Pour la santé, il est important de manger des choses qui soient bonnes au goût = n'a pas beaucoup de sens. Ensuite, chacun son avis.

Comment: Précisément: la phrase anglaise est ambiguë. J'ai donc une préférence pour _bien manger_, pour conserver cette ambiguïté.

Comment: Chacun son opinion, inutile de débattre à l'infini une question sur laquelle nous ne sommes pas d'accord. ça sert à quoi? Traduire par "bien manger" me va aussi bien que l'autre proposition. Car "bien manger", dans ce contexte, est forcément compris comme "manger sainement", on ne peut pas le remplacer par "manger des choses agréables", est-ce qu'on le pourrait?

Comment: On pourrait, par exemple si la phrase était prononcée par feu Jean-Pierre Coffe.

Comment: ça c'est un cas à part. Il faut faire preuve de bon sens, quand on traduit, on ne tient pas compte des cas limites dans un contexte particulier, mais de la façon dont est comprise la phrase. On pourrait aussi imaginer que la phrase soit prononcée par un religieux, avec des interdits, et que le sens du mot "bon" soit moral, de la nourriture morale.. On n'en fini pas.

Comment: Pour moi la traduction de choix est "*manger équilibré*", c'est ce qu'on voit dans les pubs pour la santé, etc. Ça exclut implicitement la malbouffe. Bizarre que personne en ai parlé avant ^^

Comment: Manger équilibré est bien aussi. Il y a une foule de possibilités... Certaines rajoutent un peu de sens comme la notion d'équilibre alimentaire.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec mouviciel - bien manger est plus large, et rend mieux l'ambiguite de l'anglais.  On peut tout a fait argumenter que le bon gout de la nourriture est en lui-meme un facteur de sante, et manger sainement est tellement vaguement defini qu'autant ne rien dire..

Answer (score -1):

Both are acceptables, but the second is more "french"

*de* gives more importance to the action of eating

Comment: Is there a rule when the use of *de* is acceptable? In the linked question, it looks like it's not acceptable.

Comment: there's no mistake for the 2 possibilités, no particular rules it depends of verb used. For **manger** both are coorect

Comment: I disagree, "manger de la bonne nourriture" is not bon français.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE explain why

Comment: Je l'ai expliqué dans ma réponse. De plus, la première phrase est fausse grammaticalement. Il manque le "de".

Comment: @user11550 The difference between the two question is where you placed the verb. One use "*c'est [de] <verb>*", and the other used "*je pense que <verb>*", the constructions are very different. Most of the times (but not always) after **que** you don't use *de*, and after **c'est**, it depends. For example you say "*Avec le poulet, ce que j'aime **c'est manger** la peau*".

Comment: @user11550 It's kind of like preposition after verbs, you pretty much have to know each case.

Comment: Nope.  The first one is just plain wrong.