# "en bien mangeant" or "en mangeant bien"

Tags: grammaire, verbes, adverbes, ordre-des-mots

> Je reste en forme en bien mangeant.

or

> Je reste en forme en mangeant bien.

For the [sentence](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23496/11550)

> Ce qui est important pour la santé, c'est de bien manger.

we place *bien* before *manger*. Is it the same here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In French the adverb is usually placed after the verb at a simple tense. So we would normally say :

> Je reste en forme en mangeant bien.
>
> La santé commence en mangeant bien. (Blog headline, [source](https://destinationsante.com/la-sante-commence-en-mangeant-bien.html))

but you will find some instances where the adverb will be placed before the verb. Mostly in classical French:

> A fait, en bien mangeant, l’éloge des morceaux. (Boileau, [Satire III](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Satire_III_(Boileau)))

When used in contemporary writing it sounds weird to a modern ear, it is used for a purpose (it sounds old fashioned).

> L’appétit vient en bien mangeant (newspaper headline, [source](http://www.sudouest.fr/2012/05/02/l-appetit-vient-en-bien-mangeant-703203-4043.php))

---

With the verb in the infinitive the place of *bien* is not so clear cut. You will find it can be placed either before or after the infinitive with little or no difference in meaning.

> Maigrir et bien manger. (blog headline, [source](http://www.femina.fr/Sante-Forme/Regimes-Nutrition/Maigrir-et-bien-manger-10-conseils-regime))
>
> Bien Manger, Bien Vivre. (blog headline,[source](https://destinationsante.com/rubriques/bien-manger-bien-vivre))
>
> 25 plans pour manger bien et pas cher à Paris.(blog headline,[source](https://www.buzzfeed.com/marietelling/25-plans-pour-manger-bien-et-pas-cher-a-paris?utm_term=.ps0QYkXPQp#.odpODGL4Ov))
> bien manger pour moins de 10€. (same source, further down the page)
>
> Où manger bien et pas cher au restaurant ? (Blog headline[source](http://madame.lefigaro.fr/cuisine/restaurants-peut-on-manger-bien-et-pas-cher-170415-96109))

In this last sentence we can explain the fact that *bien* is placed after the verb because we have two  coordinated adverbs and *pas cher*, would never go before the verb, so both adverbs are placed after the verb.

It might be interesting to note the use of *bien* with *vouloir*.

> Je vous prie de bien vouloir

can be used for a request in a formal situation

> Je vous prie de vouloir bien

can be used for a command (from a superior to a subordinate) in a formal situation. (See the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/vouloir)).

Comment: _La santé commence en mangeant bien_ n'est pas très heureux. _La santé commence par bien manger_ serait mieux pour ce titre de blog.

Answer (score 0):

en mangeant bien : forme courante.

en bien mangeant: forme inutilisée, quasiment snob. Il est rare d'intercaler un adverbe entre *en* et le participe présent.

bien manger : peut s'employer.