# Translation of "turn on the light"

Tags: expressions, traduction, verbes

"Could you please turn on the light?"

> Peux-tu allumer la lumière, s'il te plaît ?

Is *allumer la lumière* the appropriate translation for "turn on the light"? A [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/allumer) says so. However, it is claimed in a [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23480/translation-of-i-think-eating-good-food-is-important) that it is not good French because of the pléonasme. Can we also just say

> Peux-tu allumer, s'il te plaît ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context.  You can *allumer* all sorts of things. So you'd better mention what you are talking about.

*Allumer une allumette.

Allumer une cigarette.

Allumer un feu.

Allumer un moteur/un appareil.*
Not to mention all the figurative uses of the verb (*allumer quelqu'un* for example).

Imagine you come into a room which is dark and cold, the fireplace is nicely stacked with logs but the fire is not started. If you just say:

> *Peux-tu allumer* ?

It might not be clear if you want the fire started or the light turned on, so you'll say :

> *Peux-tu allumer la lumière* ?

But if the room is getting dark and you say :

> *Il fait sombre, peux-tu allumer ?*

it's fine because mentioning *Il fait sombre* is enough to show you are talking about the light.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

You can't say "Peux-tu allumer ?", wich only means "Can you turn on ?".

"Peux-tu allumer la lumière ?" is perfect, it is the best translation for "turn on the light".

Answer (score 0):

It is both correct and pleonastic.

If I enter in a dark room and I know that a friend is close to the light switch, I would probably ask him to switch on the lignt:

> Tu peux allumer s'il te plait ?

(`Tu peux` is here a familiar interogative form, the correct one would be `Peux tu`)

But if I was asking some one with more respect, I would probably say:

> Bonjour, pouvez vous allumer la lumière s'il vous plait

simply to be more explicit